# Create vector by matching vector to a dataframe [R]

Tags: r, vector

I have the following dataframe:

```
> zCode <- sample(50:150, size = 10, replace = TRUE)
> x <- sample(50:150, size = 10, replace = TRUE)
> test <- data.frame(x,zCode )
> test
  zCode  x
1  110 114
2  108 150
3   57 100
4   53  98
5  114  67
6  143 126
7  110  95
8  106 101
9  103  70
10 149  73
```

I also have this vector:

```
> z <- c(53, 57, 110)
> z
[1]  53  57 110
```

I want to create a new dataframe based on vector Z, that pulls the maximum x value associated with that z-code, like so:

```
 Z   x
53   98
57   100
110  114
```

Comment: `set.seed()` before producing data is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possibilities. They do not use any packages.

**1)** For each element of z compute the subset of rows in test with that zCode and then take the maximum of each x:

```
data.frame(z, x = sapply(z, function(z) max(subset(test, z == zCode)$x)))
```

giving:

```
    z   x
1  53  98
2  57 100
3 110 114
```

**2)** Another approach is to use aggregate to find all the maxima and the merge with z to get just those:

```
merge(data.frame(z), aggregate(x ~ zCode, test, max), by = 1, all.x = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
    z   x
1  53  98
2  57 100
3 110 114
```

**Hote:** The input used, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- "
  zCode  x
1  110 114
2  108 150
3   57 100
4   53  98
5  114  67
6  143 126
7  110  95
8  106 101
9  103  70
10 149  73"
test <- read.table(text = Lines)

z <- c(53, 57, 110)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any easy way of tweaking the lapply code to get unique counts & add multiple conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
# Original data
dt <- data.table(zCode = c(110, 108, 57, 53, 114, 143, 110, 106, 103, 149), 
                 x     = c(114, 150, 100, 98, 67, 126, 95, 101, 70, 73))
z <- c(53, 57, 110)

# a new dataframe based on vector z
dt[zCode %in% z, max(x), by = zCode]
   zCode  V1
1:   110 114
2:    57 100
3:    53  98
```

EDIT:

```
# Keeps the columns names unchanged
dt[zCode %in% z, .(x = max(x)), by = zCode]
   zCode   x
1:   110 114
2:    57 100
3:    53  98
```